# How to use multiple fields from one model to another as foreignkey?

Tags: django, model

I am trying to use multiple fields from my Dog model as choices in MyDog model. When i create a new MyDog instance, it both shows what is in Dog.name. How can i make MyDog.breed see whats in Dog.breed?

```
class Dog(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
breed = models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class MyDog(models.Model):   
    name=models.ForeignKey(Dog,related_name='mydogname',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(Dog,related_name='mydogbreed',on_delete=models.CASCADE,to_field='breed',db_column='breed')
```

Comment: If you have class Dog you do not need to create another class MyDog, just use primary_key to define dogs. solution for this 
```dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog,related_name='mydogname',on_delete=models.CASCADE)```
now use "dog.name" and "dog.breed" for any primary_key just fetch the my dog instance.

Comment: @NVS Thank you NVS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is shows there is what you define with

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

which roughly translates to "String representation of a Dog instance". I don't think you can change depending on the ForeignKey field they are used in, but it shouldn't have any effect on functionality, only on how it is displayed. You can print the breed like this if you want:

```
my_dog = MyDog.objects.get(...)
print my_dog.breed # this prints what __str__ method prints for dog
print my_dog.breed.breed # this prints breed field of dog
```

Comment: You helped me understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

That's not how ForeignKey relationships work. When you make a relationship, you make a relationship to an object (another table), not to a specific column of that table.

So if `myDog = MyDog(name=Dog.objects.first())` creates a `MyDog` object related to the first `Dog` in the database, then `myDog.name.name` will give you the `name` field of the `Dog` and `myDog.name.breed` would give you the breed. As you can see, your models are not well defined this way.

A more logical structure would be:

```
 class Breed(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(...)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

 class Dog(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(...)

 class MyDog(models.Model):
     dog = models.ForeignKey(Dog)
     breed = models.ForeignKey(Breed)

 dog = Dog.objects.create(name='Pluto')
 breed = Breed.objects.create(name='Collie')
 my_dog = MyDog(dog=dog, breed=breed)
 my_dog.breed.name  # "Collie"
 print(my_dog.breed)  # "Collie" because of __str__()
```

Comment: You are right, the first sentence u said was how i used to understand this, thank you for enlightening me.